# .cabal file keeps reverting to template on save in Visual Studio Code

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, cabal, haskell-stack

I've been going through the book [Haskell Programming from First Principles](https://haskellbook.com/) and I've gotten to the section on testing where I've started to encounter this strange issue.

Whenever I try and edit the .cabal file for my project, every time I save it it reverts back to the template .cabal file that is generated when creating a project with stack.

I've tried saving without formatting and editing the file in Notes (I'm on Mac), saving, and then reopening the project in vscode (this also reverts the file to the template).

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?  I'm using the basic Haskell extension, the syntax highlighting extension, the debugging extension (which I have not gotten to work, anyway), and brittany for auto-formatting.

Thanks all!

Comment: Is there a `package.yaml` in your project?

Comment: @Koterpillar It does have a `package.yaml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I checked my `package.yaml` (as referenced by @Koterpillar) I realized that it was acting as a generator of sorts for my `.cabal` file.

I then edited `package.yaml` with the information I needed and it fixed my issue.  My `.cabal` file now contains the appropriate parameters.

Thanks @Koterpillar!

Comment: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#does-stack-support-the-hpack-specification